# All reasons that raise a ssh remote host identification has changed

Tags: ssh

When SSH shows

> **WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!**

I know it happens when you reinstall your remote server but I try to list **other reasons**.

I know how to solve it so please do not mark the topic as a duplicate, it is about the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Client changed his key (software reinstall or manually).
2. Server changed his key (software reinstall or manually).
3. Let's say server uses IP `12.34.56.789` and domain `example.com` is registered to that IP. You have been ssh-ing using IP, like `ssh user@12.34.56.789`, but now you ssh using domain, like `ssh user@example.com`.

These are the ones I came across personally. If someone knows any other, please comment below or edit the answer.

Comment: OK for 1 and 2 but for 3 it should add 2 entries in .ssh/know_host (one for IP, one for host/domain) ?

Comment: Yes, one for each. I removed my `.ssh/known_hosts` and tried `ssh user@12.34.56.789`, added key, tried `ssh user@example.com` and no errors... Strange... It might have to do something with how DNS is configured, not really sure... Just sharing my experience.

Comment: Or probably it had to do with local DNS cache. That's more likely than DNS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Github just have updated the RSA SSH host key recently!

> At approximately 05:00 UTC on March 24, out of an abundance of caution, we replaced our RSA SSH host key used to secure Git operations for GitHub.com.

To fix that, just add the new RSA SSH host key to `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Remove the old key by running this command:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

And add this to file `.ssh/known_hosts`

```
github.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
github.com ssh-rsa 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
```

Or only this, if others not needed.

```
github.com ssh-rsa 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
```

Keys from source here:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints